# WSCInstallProviderAndChains Always Fails

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

I am trying to use the `WSCInstallProviderAndChains` function with the following parameters:

First, I load the ws2_32.dll with Loadlibrary, then I call the function:

```
rc = lpInstallProviderAndChains(
        providerGuid,        //guid
        lpszLspPathAndFile,  //filename
        lpszLspName,         //name        
        ( IfsProvider ? XP1_IFS_HANDLES : 0 ),  //flags
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &error //error code
    );
```

It always fails with error `WSAEINVALIDPROCTABLE`. I really don't know what to do with this. I run the console as Administrator and am using Windows 7.